# Inflated an object into itself

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, sculpting, geometry

I have a helmet with horns, I wanted bigger horns, inflated in sculpt mode and it caused overlapping geometry. Normally I have solved this but it's not playing ball this time.

I've tried *Limited Dissolve*, select by trait, remeshing. I don't want to have to unpick it all manually.

Intersect (Knife) made a bit of progress as I have vertices at the intersect, and I've merged by distance:

[image]

This is the interior, and what I'm trying to sort out:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: hello, do you really need so many faces? Why don't you work with a low-poly mesh?

Comment: I was about to start adding detail before I changed my mind. it's still only 12k verts

Comment: it's hard to understand what you're trying to do, checker deselect function is a good trick to simplify a topology, but maybe share your file

Comment: I would personally block out horns and base helmet shape as all separate objects first. Then 1. merge objects; 2. remesh;3.  retopo to a clean lowpoly; 4. subdivide and start adding details.